# Android Tablet and HTML5 Canvas not working

Tags: html, android, html5-canvas

I have an Android Asus Eee Pad Transformer android.

My problem is that I've created a html5 canvas to draw using touch and all I get is a point, cannot draw.

Is this to do with the browser or with the Tablet?

Anyone have any ideas on what the problem could be please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tested another browser such as Dolphin? This should give you a better idea as to whether it's the tablet or the browser.

My first guess would be to say it's more the tablet and the way your finger gets translated to the canvas. The canvas may not interpret you sliding your finger as a mouse click and drag.